# c# Smartsheet API Display Date

Tags: c#, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

I have written a C# program that pulls data from SmartSheet then inserts the data into a SQL Database.  Everything is working perfectly except for dates.  I have searched this site plus others on how to pull the date information in a format that can be loaded into the SQL database.  I have an outstanding question to the API group at SmartSheet.  The contact person at SmartSheet admitted that they did not have documentation on how to perform this function.  There is documentation on how to format the data to insert into a sheet, but not how to format the data in pulling a date format from Smartsheet.  Can anybody help?  Thanks.

Comment: What does the date field data look like?

Comment: In SmartSheet is defined as a Date field with the format of mm/dd/yy.  When I use DisplayValue it always has a value of null.  Which the documentation states DisplayValue does not work.  I just need to know what command to use to pull the data in any numeric format, then the program can format the date.

Comment: It sounds like the `numericDates=true` query parameter might be useful. You can pass that back with your read requests (like GET sheet) to the API.

Comment: Could you post the code that you're using to try to retrieve the date?

Answer (score 3):

Have you already read the [Dates and Times section](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#dates-and-times) of the Smartsheet API docs? Here's the relevant excerpt:

> The Smartsheet API returns all dates and times in the UTC time zone in
>   [ISO-8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), that is, YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ

There is also a query parameter (`numericDates=true`) you can pass with your request if you want to receive the date in Unix Epoch Time.

Is there a reason you don't want to store the ISO-8601 date in your SQL database? That format contains all the information you might need in the future. You could also apply any date formatting logic you want either before or after you store the date.

Comment: I have read that section.  I still don't see how to address dates.  The numericDates parameter appears to only work in adding a parm to a URL.  I want to pull the date in any format into my c# program.  I am using the API for address a cell in a row of statusCellTask.  Do I need to use something else or when I load the sheet do I need to set the parms for date format to numerics?

Answer (score 2):

I am new to c# and .net, so I supposed it was just me.  But here is the answer.

```
statusCellTask = getCellByColumnName(row, "Start");
 var varStart = statusCellTask.Value;
 if (varStart is null
{ command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sqlStart", ""); }
else
{
string Start = varStart.ToString();
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sqlStart", Start);
}
```

I hope that this helps someone with what I have struggled with.

Comment: Thanks for following up with the solution. Teaching others is a great way to solidify what you're learning. Can you add a little more context around what the problem was?

Answer (score 0):

Taylor's answer is correct. You can pass the `numericDates` query parameter to get a numeric epoch value. That said, if you prefer to take the ISO-8601 string, there are C# ways to convert that to other formats. You could then convert into whatever requirements your SQL database has.

```
var convertedTime = DateTime.ParseExact(cellDateValueString, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I am sorry for my inability to communicate my question.  I am trying to pull the date out of a SmartSheet cell.  No matter what I do I always receive null.  How do I get the date value into cellDateValueString.

Comment: Ah, that's very different from what you asked. Please post the code you're using to try to retrieve the value from Smartsheet.

Comment: foreach (Row row in sheet.Rows)
                        {
 statusCellTask = getCellByColumnName(row, "Start");
                                string Start =  statusCellTask.Value.ToString  ;
                                if (Start == DateTime.MinValue && Start == DateTime.MaxValue )
                                { command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sqlStart", Start); }
                                else
                                { command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sqlStart", ""); }j  Where Start is a date.

Comment: I hope that snippet helped.  I can add more code if needed.

Comment: // Load the entire sheet
var sheet = ss.SheetResources.GetSheet(
sheetId,           // long sheetId
null,                       // IEnumerable<SheetLevelInclusion> includes
null,                       // IEnumerable<SheetLevelExclusion> excludes
null,                     // IEnumerable<long> rowIds
null,                       // IEnumerable<int> rowNumbers
null,                       // IEnumerable<long> columnIds
null,                       // Nullable<long> pageSize
null                        // Nullable<long> page
 );

Comment: Comments are not the appropriate place for your code. Please update your question with the appropriate information. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I think the question being asked is how to extract date data from the SmartSheet API.  From what I had to work out it has to do with the PaginatedResult being configured.

Example:

```
    PaginatedResult<User> users = smartsheet.UserResources.ListUsers(
    null,
    new List<ListUserInclusion> { ListUserInclusion.LAST_LOGIN },
    new PaginationParameters(true, null, null)
    );
```